# UIImagePickerController, custom UIButton and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to put a custom button into UIImagePickerController using auto layout constraints.

```
- (void)createTimerButtonFor:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
{
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Timer" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSLayoutConstraint* constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:picker.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint* constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:picker.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:100.0];
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:100.0];


[picker.view addSubview:button];

[picker.view addConstraint:constraint1];
[picker.view addConstraint:constraint2];
[button addConstraint:heightConstraint];
[button addConstraint:widthConstraint];
}
```

Is it even possible to do so? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you want the button positioned? And in what way it isn't working (e.g. "the button doesn't show up," or "the button isn't in the right place")? Also, views involved in constraints must be in the view hierarchy before applying constraints that reference them. You should be getting an exception or at least a log output.

Answer (score 1):

Dzior, I think it would be quite hard to add the button to the picker view and let autolayout to position it for you. I guess maybe it is not fully using the auto layout.

I have tried to disable it from rotating but all the tricks for before iOS 8 is not working properly on iOS 8.

It will be easier to create an overlay view and put your button in the overlay view because you have full control of the overlay view class.